# How to use Panda Wireless PAU09 wireless adapter with macOS Big Sur version 11.6.4

Tags: macos, mac, wifi, big-sur, driver

I have a Panda Wireless PAU09 wireless adapter, but am not able to get it to work with my mac. I am generally unaware of this type of thing and so I downloaded the most recent driver on their website (10.14). This did not work. The `.dmg` would not open. I assume the drivers for this sort of thing are very version dependent?

Does anyone know a possible workaround the get the adapter to work with my mac?
Also is it even worth it/more powerful than the built in one a 13 inch 2018 MacBook pro?

Comment: If you can’t mount the .dmg, the file may be corrupt. Until you get a valid download, you won’t be able to install the drivers.  If you continue to have issues with the file, contact the manufacturer for assistance.

Comment: darn. I guess I will try to contact the company as the drivers listed on the company are not compatible.